# When clicked on button, how can i make the returned message appear on the same page without other code?

Tags: php, html, forms, select, switch-statement

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Greeting Service!</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post" action="">
<h1>What's Your Name?</h1>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name Here" />
<h4>Greet me in:
<select name="language">
<option value="option1">English</option>
<option value="option2">Chinese</option>
<option value="option3">French</option>
</select>
</h4>
<input type="submit" value="Greet Me!" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['language'])) {
$language = $_POST['language'];
switch ($_POST['language']) {
case "option1":
$result = "Hello, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
case "option2":
$result = "你好, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
case "option3":
$result = "Bonjour, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
}
}
?>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how i can make the greet appear just by itself on the exact same page, but without the text-box to enter a name, the select option and the submit button. Because currently when i enter a name, and choose for e.g. to greet the name in english, it echoes it next to the submit button. I want it to echo on the same page, but without the rest of the page showing. Is there a way i can do that?

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. if you just need to show what being selected from drop down only then it can be done through javascript but if you need to fetch that selected value into PHP like you need to execute some code PHP after selection made then you need to use AJAX. let me know what exactly you want??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Greeting Service!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['language'])) {
    $language = $_POST['language'];
    $result='';
    switch ($_POST['language']) {
    case "option1":
    $result = "Hello, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
    break;
    case "option2":
    $result = "你好, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
    break;
    case "option3":
    $result = "Bonjour, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
    break;
    }
    echo $result;
    }
else{
    ?>
    <center>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <h1>What's Your Name?</h1>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name Here" />
    <h4>Greet me in:
    <select name="language">
    <option value="option1">English</option>
    <option value="option2">Chinese</option>
    <option value="option3">French</option>
    </select>
    </h4>
    <input type="submit" value="Greet Me!" />

    </form>
    </center>
<?php }?>
    </body>
    </html>
```